# How do I access UnaryPredicate interface and how does it compare to Predicate interface?

Tags: java, import, interface, package

While going through practice exercises for Java tutorials, I have noticed the mention of the UnaryPredicate interface in the code for both questions and answers. Example:

> How do you invoke the following method to find the first integer in a list that is relatively prime to a list of specified integers?
>
> `public static <T> int findFirst(List<T> list, int begin, int end, UnaryPredicate<T> p)`

Part of the answer the provided included the following information:

> The generic UnaryPredicate interface is defined as follows:
>
> ```
> public interface UnaryPredicate<T> {
>     public boolean test(T obj);
> }
> ```

However, even when I was in a code compiler, I could not access this interface, and the aforementioned answer does not show how to do so. I did also see that I have access to a `Predicate<T>` interface, which seems to have similar purpose, but more complex code. Mainly for the purpose of understanding, how can I efficiently access UnaryPredicate? Aside from what I mentioned, what is the difference between Predicate and UnaryPredicate? Is UnaryPredicate depreciated, and if so, is that why I can't automatically access it? Is it just something that was made up for the tutorial question?

**Note:** UnaryPredicate does appear to exist in a number of packages, though some of them appear to be made by unfamiliar third party sources and/or individual programmers. While I was not 100% certain on which one to try, I believed the one from inside org.apache.commons.functor to be most trustworthy, since Apache seems to be a more legitimate source. Unfortunately, when I attempted to use `import org.apache.commons.functor.UnaryPredicate;`, I received an error stating "package org.apache.commons.functor does not exist." Even when I shortened it to `import org.apache`, I received the error "package org does not exist." I saw sources online about downloading particular files for packages and examples of adding it to particular java projects. However, I want to make sure I use the right file and/or source. I also want to make sure that it is not necessarily limited to just one project, similarly to how I am able to implement java across my computer or particular modules across my projects.